# Trouble understanding Android's doc about downscaling large bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

My question is: how come this doc exists and is posted and re-posted around a lot, and no one has ever encountered a problem with it. My conclusion is that I have misunderstood the logic of the code or the whole topic, but then can someone please explain? Here's the story:

I am trying to downscale a large bitmap, following android's doc here:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

and more specifically with this code snippet:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

I am trying to make a 100x600 image fit into a 400x400 ImageView. So my app enters the first if() statement, because the height is too big, but then doesn't do anything because it doesn't enter the while() statement - half the height is not too big!

I don't really see the point of checking halfWidth and halfHeight, when it's the entire image that has to fit...

I would write it like this:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
                BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((height / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    || (width / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }


        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

import com.serviceledger.corporatefloor.modals.ImageData;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by rohit.h on 1/29/2016.
 */
public class ImageCompresser {

    private static ImageCompresser instance;

    private ImageCompresser() {
    }

    public static ImageCompresser getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ImageCompresser();
        }

        return instance;
    }



    public ImageData compressImage(Context mContext,String imageUri) {

        String filePath = imageUri;
        // String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not
        // loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

        // max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as
        // 816x612

        /*
         * float maxHeight = 816.0f; float maxWidth = 612.0f;
         */
        float maxHeight = 1080.0f;
        float maxWidth = 800.0f;

        float imgRatio = actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        // width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the
        // image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of
        // the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

        // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low
        // on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            // load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        // check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        //    displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
        //        displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
         //       displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
          //      displayLogs("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }

            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename(mContext,filePath);
        // File image = new File(getFilename(), System.currentTimeMillis() +
        // ".jpg");
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            // write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by
            // filename.
            boolean didWrite = scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);

            out.close();

            System.out.println(didWrite);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageData data = new ImageData();
        data.setBitmap(scaledBitmap);
        data.setUrl(filename);
        return data;

    }

    private String getRealPathFromURI(Context mContext,String contentURI) {
        Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    private String getFilename(Context mContext,String originalname) {

        ImageCache imageCache = new ImageCache(mContext);
        File file = imageCache.getCacheDirectory();

        // return file;
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "F_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        return uriSting;

    }

}

Second class:

public class ImageCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"yourpackagename");
        }
        else{
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();     
        }

        if(!cacheDir.exists()){
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

    }

    public File getCacheDirectory(){
        return cacheDir;
    }


    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }
ModalClass:-

public class ImageData {
    private String Url;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public boolean isImageAvailable() {
        return isImageAvailable;
    }

    public void setIsImageAvailable(boolean isImageAvailable) {
        this.isImageAvailable = isImageAvailable;
    }

    private boolean isImageAvailable;

    public boolean isImageDeleteable() {
        return isImageDeleteable;
    }

    public void setIsImageDeleteable(boolean isImageDeleteable) {
        this.isImageDeleteable = isImageDeleteable;
    }

    private boolean isImageDeleteable;
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return Url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        Url = url;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but I'm not actually looking for a solution to down-scale an image (As I guess that is what you are suggesting?). Just to know if I am misusing the official doc (maybe it is intended to just scale images that are more than twice bigger than the target?)

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is not so perfect due to the quality loss.

In your case, the width of the picture is 100, but you need to scale it to 400. For the sake of graphics quality, it had better to load the original image without compression. The code in the doc will return 1, so it won't compress the picture. That may be the best solution, and has the same result with yours.

Let's assume the raw image is 402x402, a bit larger than the view. Your method will return 2, causing your app load the subsampled version with the dimension of 201x201 and then scale it to 400x400. Clearly, it's better to make a larger image fit in a smaller view than enlarge it. All of all, the doc thinks that if the image is not twice larger than it needs to be, it should be loaded directly and shrink to the size of view. Otherwise, load the subsampled version to save the memory space and make the subsampled one shrink to the needed size.

As the method is defined by you, you can refine the code according to your situation. i.e. if you need to control the memory space and needn't pay so much attention to image quality, ignore the doc's idea.

That's all :)